# Hibernate calls sequence.nextVal twice

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my code for employee class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_seq", sequenceName = "seq_account")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "account_seq")
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private Integer accountId;
    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private Integer accountNumber;

    @OneToOne
    private Employee employee;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Account class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "emp_seq", sequenceName = "seq_employee")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "emp_seq")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Integer employeeId;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
    private String employeeName;
    //getters and setters
}
```

This is test class

```
Account a = new Account();
a.setAccountNumber(12345);
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setEmployeeName("emp-1");
a.setEmployee(e);
em.persist(e);
em.persist(a);
```

and following is the output sql that are generated for above test

```
Hibernate: drop table ACCOUNT cascade constraints
Hibernate: drop table EMPLOYEE cascade constraints
Hibernate: drop sequence seq_account
Hibernate: drop sequence seq_employee
Hibernate: create sequence seq_account start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create sequence seq_employee start with 1 increment by 50
Hibernate: create table ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID number(10,0) not null, ACCOUNT_NUMBER number(10,0), employee_EMPLOYEE_ID number(10,0), primary key (ACCOUNT_ID))
Hibernate: create table EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID number(10,0) not null, EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar2(255 char), primary key (EMPLOYEE_ID))
Hibernate: alter table ACCOUNT add constraint FKg2gm43aorntmns07tkd6h9osd foreign key (employee_EMPLOYEE_ID) references EMPLOYEE
Sep 07, 2015 5:14:29 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete

Hibernate: select seq_employee.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select seq_employee.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select seq_account.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select seq_account.nextval from dual

Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, employee_EMPLOYEE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

as you can see the part of sequence generation for ids hibernate calls `seq_emplyee.nextval` twice also for `seq_account` too. I am confused here why hibernate calls this twice?

Comment: This is just a guess, but recent versions of Hibernate use a hi/lo generator rather than a plain sequence generator by default. Perhaps the generator initializes itself with two calls in order to double-check the increment or something? If so you should be able to insert 49 additional accounts before the sequence is used next time. If you prefer to use plain sequences, add allocationSize=1 to the SequenceGenerator annotation.

Comment: @user2612030 you're right, with allocation size 1 it calls it just one time.